# Installing netcdf libraries - processor not allowed error

Tags: software-installation, compiling

I'm trying to install netcdf libraries (v3.6.3), as I need them to be compiled with mcmodel=large to allow a simulation to run (the simulation uses ifort, and currently gives 'relocation truncated to fit' errors) in some of the netcdf functions.

The method I post below used to work fine on my old computer, but now I'm on a different computer (using Red Hat, CentOS release 6.5) I get error messages.

Basically I do the following:

```
export CC=icc 
export CXX=icpc 
export CFLAGS='-O1 -xT -ip -no-prec-div -mcmodel=large -shared-intel -traceback -static-intel' 
export CXXFLAGS='-O1 -xT -ip -no-prec-div -mcmodel=large -shared-intel -traceback -static-intel' 
export F77=ifort 
export FC=ifort
export F90=ifort
export FFLAGS='-O1 -xT -ip -no-prec-div -mcmodel=large -shared-intel -traceback -static-intel' 
export CPP='icc -E' 
export CXXCPP='icpc -E'

cd netcdf-3.6.3

./configure --enable-large-file-tests --prefix=my_path_to_netcdf --disable-cxx
make check
```

And then I get the following output (only copied in the last few lines with errors):

```
*** Creating fills.nc.
*** SUCCESS!
PASS: create_fills.sh

Fatal Error: This program was not built to run on the processor in your system.
The allowed processors are: Intel(R) Core(TM) Duo processors and compatible Intel processors with supplemental Streaming SIMD Extensions 3 (SSSE3) instruction support.

FAIL: nf_test

Fatal Error: This program was not built to run on the processor in your system.
The allowed processors are: Intel(R) Core(TM) Duo processors and compatible Intel processors with supplemental Streaming SIMD Extensions 3 (SSSE3) instruction support.

FAIL: tst_f77_v2

Fatal Error: This program was not built to run on the processor in your system.
The allowed processors are: Intel(R) Core(TM) Duo processors and compatible Intel processors with supplemental Streaming SIMD Extensions 3 (SSSE3) instruction support.

FAIL: ftest
 *** Testing netCDF-3 Fortran 90 API.
 *** SUCCESS!
PASS: tst_f90
=========================================
3 of 5 tests failed
Please report to support@unidata.ucar.edu
=========================================
```

I have tried replacing the -xT with other options (-xsse, -xsse2, -xssse3) but to no avail. The available flags are:

```
awk '/model name|flags/' /proc/cpuinfo | head -2

flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nonstop_tsc extd_apicid amd_dcm aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core cpb npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold bmi1
```

Can anyone offer any guidance? I really don't know what I'm doing with computers. I think the problem may be that my new computer has AMD processors, while my old one had Intel.

Many thanks,

Liam